# How can go module only download package in a subdirectory of a repository?

Tags: git, go, go-modules

I created a module named A and push it to my company's private repo.

The repo's address is xxx.com/inf/client.git and A module is a sub directory so A module is named as xxx.com/inf/client.git/A

When I'm using the module, I import it in my code

```
import (
    "xxx.com/inf/client.git/A"
)
func main() {
    A.XXX()
}
```

When I use go build to build the code, go module can find module A and start to download. But the problem is that there're so many sub directories of the same level with A and they will all be downloaded which I'm not expecting.

Can anybody help with this? I only want xxx.com/inf/client.git/A to be download without downloading xxx.com/inf/client.git/B(C,D...) because they're not used at all.

Comment: Please read How to Write Go Code carefully and stick to it. Stop using crazy names like client.git. Also: Only whole repos can be cloned. It is impossible to do what you want.

Comment: Hi @Volker the names are only for illustration. I don't use names like these in practice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not supported.

If for some reason you *really* don't want to download the other code in that module, create a separate module in a separate repo.

There's practically never any reason to create a separate module for this reason. All it does is save a few kb of disk space, and disks are cheap--usually far cheaper than the developer time it takes to handle more repos/modules.